# Asking the user to review the app after a certain number of launches

Tags: swift, swiftui, storekit, review

I'd like to ask the user to review the app after a certain number of launches. But for a reason I don't understand, the "StoreKit review pop-up" isn't shown. The `if let scene =` code is however correct because in a button it works well.

```
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    @AppStorage("launchNumber") var launchNumber: Int = 0

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear { review() }
        }
    }

    func review() {
        launchNumber += 1
        // print(launchNumber)
        guard launchNumber == 2 else { return }
        if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know why it's not shown when `launchNumber == 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.task` instead, `onAppear` is known for having issues presenting other `View`s without a delay.

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .task { review() }
    }
}
```

If you absolutely have to use `onAppear` you can set a delay.

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .onAppear { 
                 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    review() 
                 }
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `.task` didn't work but the second solution did. So I'll stick with it. Thanks!

Comment: `task != UIApplication`